# Is it possible to call a function in a parent component in React Native?

Tags: react-native, reactjs

I'm still very new to React Native, and I think this question is a fundamental misunderstanding of React.

I'm trying to open a modal from the press of a [NavigationBar](https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-navbar) button. Both the custom component I'm using ("react-native-modal-picker") and the React Native Modal use child components to trigger the event. I can't figure out how to open the modal from the press of the rightButton prop.

```
<ModalPicker 
    data = {[
        {key: '1', label: '1'},
        {key: '2', label: '2'},
        {key: '3', label: '3'}
    ]}
    initValue = 'Select option'
    selectStyle={{
        height: 200
    }}>
    <NavigationBar
        title={{ title: "ModalTest" }}
        rightButton={{ title: "Open Modal"
        handler: () => ModalPicker.open() }}
    />
 </ModalPicker>
```

I'm trying to determine if I can call open(), a function of the ModalPicker component from "rightButton" prop of the NavigationBar component.

The component for [ModalPicker](https://github.com/d-a-n/react-native-modal-picker/blob/master/index.js) does have a function to open and does work when I make a TouchableHighlight a child, but how do I call the function from within a child component props?

This is in the main component of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ref='picker'` for your parent component and refer to it by `this.refs.picker`

```
<ModalPicker
    data = {[
        {key: '1', label: '1'},
        {key: '2', label: '2'},
        {key: '3', label: '3'}
    ]}
    ref='picker'
    initValue = 'Select option'
    selectStyle={{
        height: 200
    }}>
    <NavigationBar
        title={{ title: "ModalTest" }}
        rightButton={{ title: "Open Modal",
        handler: () => this.refs.picker.open() }}
    />
 </ModalPicker>
```